# How can I use Google Analytics to see how often star ratings from my rich snippets show up in Google search and how they improve traffic when they do?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, rich-snippets

I have rich snippets for products in my store.

Currently I'm using  http://data-vocabulary.org/Review-aggregate and http://data-vocabulary.org/Rating that are showing stars in Google search results.

Is there a way that I can measure if users are seeing the stars on Google search and how this is improving my traffic?

I was wondering something like [this link about semantic analysis](http://moz.com/blog/semantic-analytics) to help me. He uses event as example, but I'd like to know I way to work with rich snippets I'm using in.

Comment: The link that you provide to the semantic analysis does not help you answer the question that you ask.   From the article: "Ultimately, this will let us drill down into analytics and view reports to see how marked up pages perform against their non-marked up counterparts."  It won't let you know anything about whether or not Google choose to show star ratings in the SERPs.

Comment: So, what can help me? :)

Comment: The only way I know of to see how Google is displaying your site is to do the search that brings it up yourself.    It is against Google's terms of service to have automated tools that do searches, so there are few tools that can help you.

Comment: Well, I don't want to see if google does that, but I want to find a way about how to measure if it's increasing user engaging through stars

Answer (score 2):

Indeed structured data in webmaster tools shows errors, but that doesnt mean that Google will put the stars up. If you want to more easily browse your site search results for stars, you can tweak the search settings to display 100 and include duplicates. This wont answer your question directly, but will give you an avenue to see what is activated in indexed pages.

Step 1) Go to google.com and click the "gear" in the top right corner. In the dropdown, click "search settings". Under Google instant predictions click "never show instant results". Now, move the slider for "results per page" all the way to 100.

Step 2) Go back to the google homepage and search for your site by using this query: `site:www.mysite.com`. Press enter and you will see X amount of pages of 100 results. Paginate through them all the way to the last page and you will see something like: `repeat the search with the omitted results included`. Click that and now you will have a list of everything.

Step 3) Manually record the pages urls that have stars activated. Hit up analytics or whatever and look up that page/bounce/funnel/etc. This should give at least some kinda very raw overview and since you recorded the urls you can keep track of them in the future.

Step 4) Reverse steps from step 1 to make your google act how it should (turn instant back on, set per-page back to default). When you wanna check again weeks later, start from step 1. If you find yourself doing this often, you can make a test account on google and use Canary branch of chrome (or as an alt signin user on your normal chrome).

Bonus: Remember that serp widgets change based on your Google+ logged in status. stars may appear for you when they dont for non-G+ users or vice versa. Try the test both ways to get a good feel for the schemascape.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually I was wondering something like this [link](http://moz.com/blog/semantic-analytics) to help me. He uses event as example, but I'd like to know I way to work with rich snippets I'm using in

Comment: @Cleyton Well that link lays out exactly how to do it, just change the script to look for reviews attrib instead of event. But tag manager is a domain::client side trigger mechanism which does not affect (nor can it affect) the querystring passed from a SERP with stars. The only current way to measure CTR engagement based on stars is to haxor into google.com/url/ redirect+track engine which appends these strings breifly before forwarding you to the clean domain. Perhaps in the future they will make that available to organics or perhaps make rich markup stats available in analytics.

Comment: @Cleyton or as Stephen Ostermiller notes, use a custom SERP logger tool/app to cobble together a DB of your star results, receive a custom analytics tracker send, and confirm callback<->callback if in DB. Make it noteworthy enough in analytics with a custom string prefix or perhaps a whole new custom UA property. It would be a tedious homebrew linkaege, but its theoretically feasible if you can find (or make) a proper SERP star logger. But then again, this type of app is "not permitted" according to Google....you could experience the hand of god for it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should check with Google Webmaster Tools, there's a menu for Structured Data here https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/structured-data and see if everything is ok.

Then, manually just look to the Top Pages that appear in organic search https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/top-search-queries?&type=urls&qv=change and see if the pages you know have structured data had some improvements in CTR since you use schema markup.

But beware, this has some obvious limitations: data about visitor behavior older than a month is too old and no more reliable (there are lot of variables that could change behavior, like competitors that stopped AdWords for certain keywords related also to your product webpage with rich snippet, and lot of other things we cannot imagine) and it's potentially a post hoc logical fallacy.

Just look if your website is implementing structured data correctly (don't consider schema markup as an improvement or SEO technique, but as an industry standard to follow).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually I was wondering something like this link(http://moz.com/blog/semantic-analytics) to help me. He uses event as example, but I'd like to know I way to work with rich snippets I'm using in.